# AttributeError: 'Trainer' object has no attribute 'lr_find'

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network, pytorch-lightning

Trainer object in pytorch lightning cannot use lr_find:

```py
trainer = L.Trainer(max_epochs=34, accelerator="auto", devices="auto")

# Method 1
tuner = L.pytorch.tuner.Tuner(trainer)
lr_find_results = tuner.lr_find(
    model,
    train_dataloaders=dataloader, 
    min_lr=0.001, # minimum learning rate
    max_lr=1.0,   # maximum learning rate
    early_stop_threshold=None
)

# Method 2
lr_find_results = trainer.tuner.lr_find(
    model,
    train_dataloaders=dataloader,
    min_lr=0.001,
    max_lr=1.0,
    early_stop_threshold=None
)
```

For some reason finding learning rate with method 2 brings up the error:

> AttributeError: 'Trainer' object has no attribute 'lr_find'

What could be the issue?...already tried updating lightning

Comment: It should be correct, look at here: https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/1.4.5/advanced/lr_finder.html#:~:text=You%20can%20also%20inspect%20the%20results%20of%20the%20learning%20rate%20finder%20or%20just%20play%20around%20with%20the%20parameters%20of%20the%20algorithm.%20This%20can%20be%20done%20by%20invoking%20the%20lr_find()%20method.%20A%20typical%20example%20of%20this%20would%20look%20like%3A

Answer (score 1):

https://lightning.ai/pages/releases/2.0.0/ Tuner and trainer are decoupled as of v2.0